# Display new line with g.drawString

Tags: java, applet

I had to make an applet that shows its own source code. This is what I have:

```
 //Reference the required Java libraries
 import java.applet.Applet; 
 import java.awt.*; 

 //The applet code
 public class FirstApplet extends Applet {

     public void paint(Graphics g) {

       //Draw a rectangle width=250, height=100
       g.drawRect(0,0,250,600); 

       //Set the color to blue
       g.setColor(Color.blue); 

       //Write the message to the web page
       g.drawString("\n //Reference the required Java libraries\n import java.applet.Applet;\n import java.awt.*; \n //The applet code\n public class FirstApplet extends Applet {\n     public void paint(Graphics g) {\n       //Draw a rectangle width=250, height=100\n      g.drawRect(0,0,250,100); \n       //Set the color to blue\n       g.setColor(Color.blue); \n       //Write the message to the web page\n       g.drawString",10,50); 
    }
 }
```

However, the \n is not making a new line. My text continues horizontally until finished. How would I crate new lines inside the g.drawString field?

Comment: Increase the y value by the text height of the previous line?

Comment: I tried making the rectangle larger, still didn't work.

Comment: That would be help.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413132/problems-with-newline-in-graphics2d-drawstring][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413132/problems-with-newline-in-graphics2d-drawstring

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try something like this (Untested):

```
public static void draw(final Graphics g, final int startX, final int startY, final String... lines){
    final FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics();
    final int spacing = metrics.getHeight() + metrics.getMaxDescent();
    draw(g, startX, startY, spacing, lines);
}

public static void draw(final Graphics g, final int startX, final int startY, final int vSpacing, final String... lines){
    int y = startY;
    for(final String line : lines){
        g.drawString(line, startX, y);
        y += vSpacing;
    }
}
```

The first method will calculate the height (based on the height and descent of the current `Font` of your `Graphics` object). The second method allows you to input a custom vertical spacing value for more customizability.

Answer (score 0):

> I had to make an applet that shows its own source code.

Two alternatives:

1. Use [`AppletContext.showDocument(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#showDocument%28java.net.URL%29) to browse to the source file.
2. Use a [`JTextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) with [`JTextComponent.read(Reader,Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) to read the source.

### BTW

1. Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).
2. Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).