# How do I indent a String with drawString();

Tags: java

`System.out.println("How \n are \n you");` produces:

`How`
`Are`
`You`

Like expected. But...

`g.drawString("How \n are \n you", xPos, yPos);` produces:

`How are you`

without the proper indentation. I understand I could just draw the string three separate times, each time lowering the y coordinate, like so:

`g.drawString("How", xPos, yPos);`
`g.drawString("are", xPos, lowerYPos);`
`g.drawString("you", xPos, evenLowerYPos);`

but this just seems sloppy. Is there a way to indent using `g.drawString();`?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413132/problems-with-newline-in-graphics2d-drawstring

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Thank you. I looked, but didn't find this thread.

Comment: `Drawstring` method doesn't support newlines.