# How to create a paragraph of text in java

Tags: java

Is there any way to make a some text appear as a paragraph, since at the moment i use,

```
private String howtoplay = "[Insert How To Play THe Game Instructions Here]";
```

When i use strings the text just goes off my game screen which is 800 pixels by 600 pixels.

How do i make it so it doesn't go out of the screen and just either just a block of text, or that when the word reaches the end of the game screen, it will start on a new line.

I have only used strings and so i have been used t using them to create small amounts of text like the title and small commands instructing what button to click.

So in short, is there any way to create a block of text without creating like another class, or just creating a bunch of strings?

EDIT:
So it turns out that i cannot create a new line break, due to the fact i have a drawString

```
g.drawString(title, ((Sea_InvadersDisplay.WIDTH/2)-(titleWidth/2))-2,      (Sea_InvadersDisplay.HEIGHT/2)-123);
```

and i have found the solution here:
[Problems with newline in Graphics2D.drawString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413132/problems-with-newline-in-graphics2d-drawstring)
So in other words i have found the solution to my problem.

Comment: Why not use `\n` - it inserts a newline?

Comment: \n ? What's that?

Comment: @Gassy [Escape characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Comment: Oh okay, i've seen what it does, it creates a new line. I didn't know this before. I will give this a try.

Comment: look at String.format

Comment: Consider next time google, before post such things on stackoverflow

Comment: I tried google, but i didn't think about looking at things like adding new lines, just searching about paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

> use can \n to break to the next line and you can use.
>   everytime you need to move to a new line or new row u just pass \n into your string

Answer (score 0):

Try to use html code.... new line in html code is represented by `<br/>` tag... so you will have something like this:

```
<html>
    <p>[Insert How To Play THe Game Instructions Here]</p>
</html>
```